# ChromeDriver hangs on a page with many images randomly for 20-30 minutes

Tags: selenium

I used ChromeDriver for automation web page interaction for a while, however, there is a random issue I'm not able to resolve. I hope to search help in this community.

- ChromeDriver: I've tried 2.12 - 2.16, all of them has this issue
- Chrome: Version 43.0.2357.134 m
- Selenium: 2.44
- JAVA: 1.7.79 X86

Symptom: When program run to the last page, it hangs there, sometimes it will cost 20-30 minutes for webdriver get back, within this time, WebDriver is out of control, program can do nothing about WebDriver. And in status bar of chrome there are some words saying "waiting for pda-ads.amazon.com"...

I don't know whether there is a solution to resolve this issue. I've tried below ways:

1. Submit a callable task with timeout of 10 seconds, in case it still hangs on, throw exception and continue, however, at this time WebDriver still hangs, I cannot get necessary information in the last page, only manually enter anther web site address will make WebDriver come back to normal
2. Maybe it's due to the first time load page will consume very long time, so I'm not sure whether a profile setting so that it might use local cache would be better
3. I even thought of to call external auto keyboard tools to get information in last page, however I don't practice yet.

Would you please give me some thoughts or tips to resolve this issue or a workaround?

PS: I've already set timeout values like this:

```
driver.manage().timeouts()
.implicitlyWait(timeOut, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
.pageLoadTimeout(timeOut * 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.setScriptTimeout(timeOut * 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

implicitlWait timeout is 10 seconds, thus pageload timeout and script timeout are both 30 seconds, I've always set these timeout values, but still not works.

Comment: Is it happening with all the websites or your application only.If possible can you provide the link of the webpage you are testing.and try using latest selenium 2.46

Comment: Hi Madhan, thank you for your help, actually yesterday I've tried using selenium 2.46 and ChromeDriver 2.16 but still not work.

Comment: Actually only my application, I'm not sure whether it's related to amazon advertisement server or not...

Answer (score 0):

I think that loading that script (pda-ads.amazon.com...) is making the page to not finish loading. Selenium has a setting for the page load timeout which according to [this answer](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/2615) is left blank so it waits forever for the page to load. My best bet is that's your case. I suffered from this issue in a project, and setting a pageLoadTimeout was the solution.

You can override the value with `driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`

[Docs for Selenium Timeouts](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html)

Comment: Hi nberget, thank you very much, I've add appendix in my previous question, actually I've set pageloadtimeout to 30 seconds and script timeout to 30 seconds already before, but it does not work. I'm not sure whether this timeout settings works or there is some other issue blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar problem, unfortunately I did not find solution yet. I am using docker container with `Ubuntu 14.04` and `chrome + Xvfb`. Below is piece of docker log when the chrome was freezing:

```
09:18:37.902 INFO - Done: [click: 30 [[ChromeDriver: chrome on LINUX (10d5ee0a45a69b5ac2001c3ef83c4f3f)] -> id: ecu-man-9092]]
09:18:38.908 INFO - Executing: [refresh])
09:18:39.584 INFO - Done: [refresh]
09:18:40.594 INFO - Executing: [delete session: 8c2fd722-a7ba-4afc-9838-41130ce6280f])
09:18:41.151 INFO - Done: [delete session: 8c2fd722-a7ba-4afc-9838-41130ce6280f]
09:19:12.060 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{platform=ANY, browserName=chrome, version=}]])
09:19:12.061 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{platform=ANY, browserName=chrome, version=}]
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248304) on port 18887
**[0.506][WARNING]: PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation**
```

Maybe it brings something useful for debugging of this issue.

> Selenium 2.46.0

Answer (score 0):

We can set pageLoadTimeout, once set it wil be there throught the webdriver session, and if the exception is thrown because of timeout then we can't restore same session so need to create new instance.

```
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        //waits 10 seconds for page to load
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        try {
            driver.get("https://yourdomain.com");
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();

            //create new instance of webdriver
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            //waits 5 minutes for page to load
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("https://yourdomain.com");
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

This issue was not resolved at WebDriver level finally, so another workaround finally make it works.

I'm not using webdriver to do website or app test but to do some automatic tasks, thus I get cookies from current webdriver and use a HttpPost to replace the time consuming and unpredictable webdriver behaviors.

Now it works very well. The frozen and hang on issue never occurs anymore.